# EasyUI reload won't update data

Tags: datagrid, jquery-easyui

I submit a form through AJAX and upon success I try to reload the datagrid.  The grid does refresh, but it does not reflect the value I just posted - as if it didn't query the updated DB.

```
$('#mupdate').live('click',function(){      
    var objectid=$('#objectid').val();
    var docname=$('#docname').val();
    var jsonurl = urlcurrentbase + '/doc/update/'+ docname +'/'+ objectid;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: jsonurl,
        data: $("#mainform").serialize(),
        success: function(data){
            $('#mrdg').datagrid('reload');
        }
    });
});
```

I load the grid through PHP.

```
       <table id="mrdg" class="mrdg" data-options="url:'<?php echo URL::base();?>/json/getmainlist/<?php echo $urldocname?>',pagination:true,singleSelect:true,striped:true,fit:true,pageSize:50">
```

Answer (score 0):

no need to call ajax since datagrid already does that.. just call the url in datagrid's url..

try this,

```
 $('#mupdate').live('click',function(){      
 var objectid=$('#objectid').val();
 var docname=$('#docname').val();
 var jsonurl = urlcurrentbase + '/doc/update/'+ docname +'/'+ objectid;

 $('#mrdg').datagrid({url: jsonurl});
```

this should do ...

Answer (score 0):

Can you try,

```
<table id="mrdg" class="easyui-datagrid" data-options="url:'<?php echo URL::base();?    >/json/getmainlist/<?php echo $urldocname?>',pagination:true,singleSelect:true,striped:true,fit:true,pageSize:50">
```